# Understanding LED datasheet terms

Tags: voltage, led, current, datasheet

I was looking through an [LED datasheet](http://www1.futureelectronics.com/doc/EVERLIGHT%C2%A0/334-15__T1C1-4WYA.pdf) for an LED I am using and came across some terms that I am not familiar with. I a new to electronics, and have looked on the internet for explanations, but they provide relatively (to me) in-depth and complicated answers.

```
(Continuous) Forward Current
(Zener) Reverse current
Peak Forward Current(Duty /10 @ 1KHZ)
Reverse Voltage 
Forward Voltage

Electrostatic Discharge
```

Any help in understanding these would be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `(Continuous) Forward Current` - how much maximum current can be put through the LED (30 mA for the LED in question) continuously (as opposed to `peak forward current`)
- `(Zener) Reverse current` - it has zener diodes internally protecting the LED and these are limited to a certain amount of current before they might fail. The reverse current is that limit.
- `Peak Forward Current(Duty /10 @ 1KHZ)` - tells you that you can exceed the continuous current (30 mA) by using 100 mA ONLY if the duty cycle of the applied current waveform is 10% i.e. you can apply 100 mA for 100 microseconds every 1 milli-second.
- `Reverse Voltage` - this is the nominal reverse voltage of the in-built zener diodes (5 volts) before it starts to heavily conduct (\$I_R\$ >> 50 uA) - see also `Zener Reverse Voltage` = 5.2 volts at Iz = 5 mA. See also `Zener Reverse Current` of 100 mA (maximum rating)
- `Forward Voltage` - this is the typical voltage across the LED when feeding it at 20 mA (between 3.0 and 3.6 volts)
- `Electrostatic Discharge` - this tells you that the device is capable of withstanding an ESD event of 4000 volts based on the typical mode of a human (body model) touching the device when in circuit.

Comment: This is great, thanks :). What does nominal mean? Also where did you get 20mA from?

Comment: @MaltedWheaties page 4 under "conditions".

Comment: Oh I see. Does this mean that the LED will draw 20mA? Isn't that quite high for an LED?

Comment: 20 mA is probably the most common value for LEDs but can be a lot higher on some.

Comment: 20 mA is the current the manufacturer used for the specifications.  The LED will happily operate at lower currents, but will be dimmer - you have to regulate the current, usually by placing a resistor in series with the LED.